# Change whole column data format from yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm to dd/mm/yyyy VBA

Tags: excel, vba, date

I am trying to convert the data format from yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm to dd/mm/mmmm 
I've been trying different solutions but none of them works, the closest one was this:

```
Columns("I:I").Replace What:=" *", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart
Columns("I:I").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("11"), _
DataType:=xlDelimited, FieldInfo:=Array(1, xlDMYFormat)
Columns("I:I").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
```

But it throws me an error in this two lines:

```
   Columns("I:I").Replace What:=" *", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart
  Columns("I:I").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("11"), _
```

Comment: "...it throws me an error..."  Why not provide the message from that error?

Comment: Why are you using VBA for this when you can use a custom number format in Excel?

Comment: I would suggest that you start a macro recording, then change the format as per @jclasley suggestion, then when you stop recording you can inspect the code in VBA developer tab

Comment: Does Excel understand the dates as such, or it thinks it's text? If it understands the dates as `Date` values, all you need is a `NumberFormat` - avoid treating dates as strings, your life will be much simpler.

Comment: Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "dd\/mm\/yyyy"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help.

```
Sub test()
On Error Resume Next
Columns("I:I").Replace What:=" *", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart
Columns("I:I").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("11"), _
DataType:=xlDelimited, FieldInfo:=Array(1, xlDMYFormat)
Columns("I:I").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Columns("A:A").Select

Selection.NumberFormat = "dd\/mm\/yyyy"

and back

Selection.NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"

Comment: Although your suggestions will work, there is no good reason to use [`Select` or `Selection`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba), and there is no good reason to [escape the forward slashes](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/number-format-codes-5026bbd6-04bc-48cd-bf33-80f18b4eae68?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US).

Comment: Dear Ron,
this example comes from the macro recorder. No letter is my authorship :-)

Comment: Most of the time, you need to edit the output from the macro recorder in order to turn it into good code.

Comment: You might also want to read this article about [The Macro Recorder Curse](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2019/06/30/the-macro-recorder-curse/)